# how to send struck via a select in unbutton

Tags: swift, struct, swift5, sender

how can I pass this populated struct to my func ?

```
let dict = DictView(viewP: newView, gradiP: gradi, tituloP: titulo, setaP: buttonChevron, textViewP: newTextView)
        buttonChevron.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hideOrShowSave(sender: dict)), for: .touchUpInside)   
    }

    @objc func hideOrShowSave(sender: DictView){
}
```

Comment: like this I find this error Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

Method's can't be marked as `@objc` if their parameters take things such as structs that can't be bridged to Objective-C. Why do you believe that your method needs to be marked `@objc`?

Comment: because the sector only accept @objc functions and I need the selector to trigger some function

Comment: You will need to re-design your model so it doesn't try to send a struct to the method, or change the method's signature so it doesn't have a non-Objective-C parameter.